# How to show Wine System tray icons in the system top bar ? ( Ubuntu 18.04 )

Tags: 18.04, wine, gnome-shell, system-tray

I use a lot of windows applications on my Ubuntu and many of them have an icon in the system tray , which is shown as small window instead of being integrated with the system tray of Ubuntu where native applications icons are being shown ?

Comment: The answer would probably be desktop environment (DE) specific. I added the [gnome-shell] tag as the standard Ubuntu 18.04 has GNOME by default. If you're using another DE (e.g. Unity/KDE/MATE/Xfce etc.) please [edit] your question and add that info.

Comment: Same problem exists in Ubuntu 18.10. Found some [old suggestions on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/347tkc/how_to_fix_wine_system_tray_as_a_window_on/) but `libappindicator` was already installed, and installing `sni-qt` didn't have any affect. I'll try the suggested [System tray indicator for Unity](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-systemtray-unity) and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 currently, so I didn't test my solution in Ubuntu 18.04.
But, I suggest that you should use [Topicons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/).

As I know, Ubuntu 18.04 has Gnome shell version 3.28 and Topicons Plus supports it.

On Ubuntu 20.04, I could install it in official apt repository. (gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus). Please try it on Ubuntu 18.04.